# How do I can use functional programing to transform dictionary to IndexPath array?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have this kind of dictionary.

```
let sections = ["A": ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"], "B": ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]]
```

I need to fetch all keys and sort them before IndexPath array creation.

```
let sectionsKeys = Array(sections.keys).sorted()
```

Now I need to transform this dictionary to IndexPath array.

```
var indexPathes = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
```

So my attempt is quite straightforward.

```
for (sectionPos,key) in sectionsKeys.enumerated() {
    guard let items = sections[key] as? [String] else {
        break
    }
    for (itemPos,_) in items.enumerated() {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: itemPos, section: sectionPos)
        indexPathes.append(indexPath)
    }
```

}

In this way I receive expected result.

But I am looking for solution that will use functional programing to achieve same result.

Comment: Note that a dictionary is an unordered collection. There is no guarantee that "Section 1" will always be the first item in the enumeration.

Comment: @MartinR yes you are right I edit my question.

Comment: Try with Sequence - reduce()

Comment: Half part using map //from mobile so not typed well. Get all keys - let allkeys  = Array(dict.keys)
Sort if needed let allkeys = Array(dict.keys).sorted()
var indexpaths = [IndexPath]()
for (section, key) in allkeys.enumerated {
   var item = 0
   Indexpaths.append(dict[key].map(){
       let path = IndexPath(item, section)
       Item += 1
       return path
   })
}

Comment: @jpulikkottil usually (and in this case it works for sure) when you declare an empty array, then populate it inside a loop, you can just use a single `map` instead, which is a more functional approach

Comment: @DávidPásztor I am not aware of this 'section.value.indices' thanks David.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should sort the `sections` Dictionary (resulting in an array of tuples), since Dictionary is unordered by definition, so there's no guarantee that by iterating through the Dictionary itself you will get the desired results.

Afterwards you can enumerate the ordered collection, then use a combination of `flatMap` and `map` to create the `IndexPath`s. You need `flatMap` when iterating through the sections to flatten out the array of `IndexPath`s returned by the nested `map`.

Instead of iterating through an enumerated collection to only get the indexes, you can just iterate through the indices themselves using `section.value.indices`, where `value` is of type `[String]`.

```
let sections = ["Section 1": ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"], "Section 2": ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]]

let indexPaths = sections.sorted(by: {$0.key < $1.key}).enumerated().flatMap({sectionPos, section->[IndexPath] in
    return section.value.indices.map({ itemPos->IndexPath in
        IndexPath(row: itemPos, section: sectionPos)
    })
})
```

Output:

> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]]

Comment: Thx for the explanation.